# Is it necessary to provide links to the mentioned softwares' websites on my CV?

Tags: cv, software, website

I am writing my CV and, in the Skills section, I have listed the name of the softwares that I've worked with. Some of them are well-known softwares, but some are open source codes that may not be known to many people. So I linked to the softwares' websites when I felt is necessary.

I wanted to ask if this is appropriate, and is not insulting (presumptuous) to, say, the professor who is reading my CV.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the software is very specific to the role for which you're applying (in which case, one would hope that anyone reviewing applications would be familiar with it...) you should probably not go into this level of detail.